# Is there a way to not have all the elements in a hide menu load on page startup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with a bunch of dropdown menus that when you click on one of the links it unhides a picture and some text. Having all of these hidden elements load on the page startup slows the page down drastically. Is there a way to make it so that the content inside of the dropdown menus only load when they are unhidden (when the dropdown menu is clicked and the images/text shown).

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: I'd look into ajax if I were you :)

Comment: Optimize your page, reduce the amount of hidden information there, shrink your HTML to the bare minimum, and *then* if it's still slow, use AJAX and/or `.append()` to load it on-demand.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$(element).append(content)` to append it from the JS.

Append doc: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

If you opt for an AJAX solution then users with Javascript turned off will not be able to see a menu at all, making for one incredibly useless site. One way to counter this would be to place your menu's code after the content in the DOM, keeping in mind that special care will be needed to make accessibility features work like "normal" with this reversed layout.

Another option would be to use AJAX to load your menu and then optionally save it in the browser's Offline Storage for faster loading on future pages. Present a very basic menu in a `<noscript>` tag with a link to a full sitemap for your non-javascript friends.

Here is a basic example using AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "menu.html"
})
  .done(function( html ) {
    $( "#menu" ).append( html );
  });
```